# Filter and map over a list in R

Tags: r, lapply

I can do a map over a list in R with `lapply`:

```
lapply(1:10,function(y) { if (y %% 2 == 0) {y+42}})
```

(Which gives me a list between 1 and 10 where every other object is NULL).

Furthermore, I can then remove each of these NULL objects with `Filter`:

```
Filter(function(x) !is.null(x),
       lapply(1:10,function(y) { if (y %% 2 == 0) {y+42}}))
```

(Which gives me a list of even numbers between 1 and 10).

Another example, let's say we want to take a list of strings, and filter out all of the strings that start with "a", and then append "Foo" to the remaining ones. The similar technique could be used:

```
Filter(function(x) !is.null(x),
       lapply(c("foo","abar","baz"),
              function(y) { if (grepl("^a",y)) {paste("foo",y)}}))
```

Is there a better way to do a fold over a list in R.

Comment: Your update gives me error.  Please check for some typos in parentheesis.  Also, I think the example would be `lapply(letters[1:10], function(x)...`

Comment: Oops, okay, it should work now, thanks.

Comment: It works again without any loop. ie. `y2 <- c("foo","abar","baz");paste('foo', y2[grepl('^a', y2)])
#[1] "foo abar"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
y <- 1:10
as.list(y[y%%2==0]+42)
```

`grep` can also work in a vector

```
grepl(paste(c(2,4,6), collapse="|"), y)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

y1 <- letters[1:10]
paste('foo', y1[grepl('^a', y1)])
#[1] "foo a"
```

Comment: This would work as %% can operate over a list. But say if the function was `grepl()`, it can only operate over an element of the list. (Or maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: @LeifAndersen  My code was based on the example you provided.  It may be better to update your post to show a more general example

Comment: @LeifAndersen  The new example also works without using a `lapply`

Comment: Wow, I guess more functions then I realized operate over lists in R, thanks.

Comment: @LeifAndersen  I don't know if this helps or not, but if you are looking for a loop solution,  `Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(...` would be a bit more compact